# Chrome Custom Tabs without intent for user

Tags: android, android-intent, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I'm trying to implement Chrome Custom Tabs but in my small example, everytime I launch a URL it asks me with which browser I'd like to open it.

I've seen some apps like Twitter official app where the Custom Tab opens without asking anything to the user. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I've followed [this](https://medium.com/@VirusThePanda/tutorial-chrome-custom-tabs-c727cf3f4ddd) tutorial, so my code is 99% the same and the issue is the same in both codes.

Comment: Can you post some the code you are using to start the chrome tabs? Maybe there's an error there...

Comment: Personally I find it not very convenient to do the whole process to set up chrome custom tabs, so i use this library https://github.com/eliseomartelli/SimpleCustomTabs.

Comment: Thanks for the library, I will take a look at it. However, I will still like to know how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

I´ve solved the issue. I was launching the URL inside a `RecyclerView` when a `CardView` was clicked.

The problem is I was warming up the tab at the same time I was launching it. After changing that, everything worked fine.